# Remove django url prefix in template

Tags: javascript, django, django-templates

I'm trying to make a cors request in javascript. This is my code:

```
        function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {

        // Check if the XMLHttpRequest object has a "withCredentials" property.
        // "withCredentials" only exists on XMLHTTPRequest2 objects.
        xhr.open(method, url, true);

      } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {

        // Otherwise, check if XDomainRequest.
        // XDomainRequest only exists in IE, and is IE's way of making CORS requests.
        xhr = new XDomainRequest();
        xhr.open(method, url);

      } else {

        // Otherwise, CORS is not supported by the browser.
        xhr = null;

      }
      return xhr;
    }

function makeCorsRequest() {
  // All HTML5 Rocks properties support CORS.
  var url = 'otherdomain.ashx?username=xxx&password=xxx&sportsBook=xxx&sportsType=xxx&gameType=xxx';

  var xhr = createCORSRequest('GET', url);
  if (!xhr) {
    alert('CORS not supported');
    return;
  }

  // Response handlers.
  xhr.onload = function() {
    var text = xhr.responseText;
    var title = getTitle(text);
    alert('Response from CORS request to ' + url + ': ' + title);
  };

  xhr.onerror = function() {
    alert('Woops, there was an error making the request.');
  };

  xhr.send();
}
```

But i can't get the request. When i look the console, http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/managebadge/otherdomain.ashx?username=xxx&password=xxx&sportsBook=xxx&sportsType=xxx&gameType=xxx 404 (NOT FOUND). How can i remove the "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/managebadge"(url prefix) in the template? i use django. Thanks.

Comment: Can I ask why you're using a get request at all for a password? Other than that its unclear what the problem is you're trying to solve

Comment: @Sayse the url is an API. GET and POST method are supported. When i execute makeCorsRequest(), there are no alert shown. Then i inspect element-console tab, there is an error, the url that i request still contain the prefix "http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/managebadge". I want to remove that prefix. Thank you.

Comment: Are you specifying the full URL in js: `var url = 'http://otherdomain.ashx?username=xxx&password=xxx&sportsBook=xxx&sportsType=xxx&gameType=xxx';`?

Comment: @doru yes, that's the full url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The browser is treating your url as a relative url. Try:

```
var url = '://otherdomain.ashx?username=xxx&password=xxx&sportsBook=xxx&sportsType=xxx&gameType=xxx';
```

or,

```
var url = 'http://otherdomain.ashx?username=xxx&password=xxx&sportsBook=xxx&sportsType=xxx&gameType=xxx';
```

Read more about how browsers parse urls here:
http://www.webreference.com/html/tutorial2/3.html

Comment: it works. but here comes another problem. XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://otherdomain..... No Access-Control-Allow-Origin header is present on the requested source. Btw thanks.